# Determine the existence of a bijection and construction

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Sorry if it might be simple but I basically can't get my head around it.

The question asks me to:

> If exists, construct a bijection between the sets $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R - \{0\}$

But I don't know how to handle it, I thought about the existence of a relationship but the absence of $\{0\}$ in the second set makes me feel lost and can't prove the existence of the bijection.

Comment: Hint:  The only problem is that we can't allow anything to map to $0$... so take what would have normally mapped to $0$ and have it map to somewhere else, and whatever would have normally mapped to that something else to something even further, so on and so forth bumping things further down.

Comment: To amplify on JMoravitz's hint, could you do it if the $\Bbb R$ was replaced by $\Bbb Z$ (the integers)?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed it it was {0}. So, if the {0} is missing this means that they can be mapped normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extended hint:*

Let $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$

One such example of a bijection could be written in the form

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x&\text{if}~x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb N\\ \square & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

leaving you to fill in the blanks for what should be written in place of the $\square$.

Comment: The " \ " means that the number x has to be in intersection between R and N right?

Comment: $A\setminus B=\{x~:~x\in A~\text{and}~x\notin B\}$.  `\setminus` is the more standard notation to denote this as opposed to `-` since $A-B$ has the meaning in some contexts as $\{a-b~:~a\in A~\text{and}~b\in B\}$.  In this context, $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb N$ is the set of all real numbers which are not natural numbers.

Comment: If you prefer, you could write this using $f(x)=\begin{cases}\square&\text{if}~x\in\Bbb N\\ x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: . . .  nice . . .

Comment: Sorry for the tremendous amount of questions, but if you do A \ B this means that you will only {....,-3,-2,-1} right?

Comment: $\Bbb Z\setminus \Bbb N = \{\dots,-3,-2,-1\}$ however $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb N=(-\infty,0)\cup(0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup\dots$ is the set of all real numbers which are not one of $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$

Answer (score 1):

Map each non-negative integer $n$ to $n+1$ and leave the rest of universe untouched. Done.

Comment: So f is gonna be f:R -> R - {0}, f(x) = x+1 right?

Comment: @CptPackage not quite since $f(-1)=0$ in your attempt

Comment: @CptPackage Not entirely (consider $f(-1)$ to see why your example doesn't work). But combine your idea there with the hint given by JMoravitz in the other answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh now I get why you put the N, to avoid that case if I am not wrong.